# the_title function to return string instead of echo in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, how to change `the_title()` function that echoes title to return string `$title` instead ?

I was trying:

```
the_title() -> $title  
the_title() = $title
```

Comment: please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

Use [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) function. It can be used to retrieve the post title. It takes an optional Post ID or WP_Post Object as parameter.

```
$title = get_the_title();
```

**OR**

Set the third parameter `$echo` to false in the [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) function. By default, `the_title()` function echoes the title. Third parameter can be used to set echoing to false, and return the title instead:

```
$title = the_title('','', false);
```